# Plot grid across columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe and I want to produce multiple plots in grid-fashion with a mapping across columns. So it might be histograms for each column, or scatterplots of each column (except x) against x.

e.g.

```
ggplot(data=iris0, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(col=Species)) +
  ylab("Sepal.Length") + ggtitle("Scatterplot of Sepal.Length against Sepal.Width")
```

but would like to autogenerate the plots for y=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width all in single grid. 
or e.g.

```
ggplot(data=iris0, aes(x=Sepal.Width, col=Species)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = Species)) +
  ylab("Sepal.Width")
```

but autogenerate the four histograms (one for each attribute) in one grid together.

`facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` would be perfect, since they arrange it nicely for you and with clear labels (that look good). But I'm not sure how they can be applied in this case (over the attributes rather than a factor like Species).

(Prefer solutions in just base-R + ggplot2, but if necessary then go ahead with a method requiring other packages)

Comment: you should "melt" or reshape the data to long format.  I tried to use `reshape()` from base R to do this but it always melts my brain ... I may give up and use a `reshape2` or `tidyr` method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From Ben Bolker comment, but using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` that is easier to remember than `reshape()` (and part of the standard tidyverse). The idea is the same: if you want to use facets on your attributes, then your attributes should be a factor.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
               names_to = "attribute") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = value, col = Species)) +
  facet_wrap(~attribute)
```